# Ignition gateway failed to start

Tags: java, gateway, jvm

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:11:41 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:11:41 | Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.42
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:11:41 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2020 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:11:41 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:11:41 |   Licensed to Inductive Automation for Inductive Automation
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:11:41 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:11:42 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/22 10:11:42 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/22 10:12:02 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/22 10:12:02 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:03 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:08 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:08 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:09 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/22 10:12:09 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/22 10:12:10 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/22 10:12:10 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:11 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:16 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:16 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:16 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/22 10:12:16 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/22 10:12:18 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/22 10:12:18 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:18 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:24 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:24 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:24 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/22 10:12:24 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/22 10:12:25 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/22 10:12:25 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:26 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:31 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:31 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:32 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/22 10:12:32 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/22 10:12:33 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/22 10:12:33 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:33 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:34 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:34 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:12:34 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:41 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:41 | Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.42
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:41 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2020 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:41 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:41 |   Licensed to Inductive Automation for Inductive Automation
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:41 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:42 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/22 10:14:42 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/22 10:14:43 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/22 10:14:43 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:43 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:49 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:49 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:49 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/22 10:14:50 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/22 10:14:51 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/22 10:14:51 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:51 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:56 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:56 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:57 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/22 10:14:57 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/22 10:14:58 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/22 10:14:58 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:14:58 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:04 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:04 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:04 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/22 10:15:04 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/22 10:15:05 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/22 10:15:05 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:06 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:11 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:11 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:11 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/22 10:15:11 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/22 10:15:13 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/22 10:15:13 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:13 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:13 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:13 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/22 10:15:13 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:02 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:02 | Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.42
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:02 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2020 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:02 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:02 |   Licensed to Inductive Automation for Inductive Automation
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:02 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:04 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/23 09:04:05 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/23 09:04:16 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/23 09:04:16 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:17 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:22 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:22 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:23 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/23 09:04:23 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/23 09:04:24 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/23 09:04:24 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:24 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:30 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:30 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:30 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/23 09:04:30 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/23 09:04:31 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2023/06/23 09:04:31 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:32 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:37 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:37 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:37 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/23 09:04:38 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/23 09:04:39 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2023/06/23 09:04:39 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:39 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:44 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:45 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:45 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/23 09:04:45 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/23 09:04:46 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2023/06/23 09:04:46 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:47 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:47 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:47 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:04:47 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 | Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.42
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2020 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 |   Licensed to Inductive Automation for Inductive Automation
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/23 09:19:52 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/23 09:19:54 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2023/06/23 09:19:54 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:54 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:19:59 | Reloading Wrapper configuration...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:20:00 | JVM process is gone.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:20:00 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/23 09:20:00 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/23 09:20:01 | WrapperManager Error: Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32,000. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/06/23 09:20:01 | WrapperManager Error: Exiting JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:20:01 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:20:05 | INT trapped.  Shutting down.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2023/06/23 09:20:05 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  I see only a *paste* without any actual question or stated OS/release provided. Why ask here?  I see nothing on-topic for this site currently (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and details in the title may not be readable when page is opened on some devices; so you need to include all question details in your actual question text.

Comment: I am getting JVM failed to start error i have switched many java versions wrapper fails to start at port 32000, there are no other processes on the port